# How to allow user update data Database SQL on html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I have a mySQL database and which stores information that the user enters by the next form:

```
<form action="demo.php" method="POST"/>
<p><label>title:</label> <input type="text" name="titre" required/></p>
<p><label>disp: </label>
    Oui&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="disponible" value="1" required/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Non&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="disponible" value="0" required/>
</p>
<p><label>Corrected: </label>
    Oui&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="corrige" value="1" required/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Non&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="corrige" value="0"required/></p>
<p><label>Notes A:</label> <input type="text" name="notes" /></p>
<p><label>Notes B </label> <input type="text" name="notes2" /></p>
<p><label>N pages </label> <input type="text" name="pages" /></p>
<p><label>Mont: </label>
    Oui&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="monte" value="1" required/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Non&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="monte" value="0" required/></p></p>
<p><label>File:</label> <input type="text" name="image" /></p>
```

```
$value = $_POST['titre'] ;
$value2 = $_POST['disponible'] ;
$value3 = $_POST['corrige'] ;
$value4 = $_POST['notes'] ;
$value5 = $_POST['notes2'] ;
$value6 = $_POST['pages'] ;
$value7 = $_POST['monte'] ;
$image = $_POST['image'] ;


$sql = "INSERT INTO mode (Titre, Disponible, Corrige, NotesCorr, NotesRed, NPages, Monte, image) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7', '$image')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo "done";
}
```

The information is stored and is displayed in a table. (If code needed I'll post here)

What I don't have any idea how to do is to let the user EDIT data that is already stored in the table.

For example, the user selects the ID and edits whatever he wants.

Any idea how can I do this?

Best regards.

Comment: Send the id of a database entry in a hidden input element in the form, use a `UPDATE ... WHERE id = ..` query.

Comment: I suggest you read and practise on how to create a basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functionality with PHP. There's many tutorials online. Here's one that I think it could help [http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-1](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: Your application is wide open to SQL injection attack. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas really helpful! I was looking all the time for this kind of tutorial and I don't know how I didn't find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Note:

- Should be using **MySQLi**, instead of deprecated **MySQL**.
- Why use `input type="text"` on a file? Let me show you how to use `input type="file"`

Replace your:

```
<p><label>File:</label> <input type="text" name="image" /></p>
```

with:

```
<p><label>File:</label> <input type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"/></p>
```

And add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your `<form>`:

```
<form action="demo.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
```

**PHP Code**:

```
$allowedExts=array("jpg","jpeg","png");
$temp=explode(".",$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$extension=end($temp);

    /* START OF FILE UPLOAD */

    if(($_FILES["image"]["size"]<8388608) && in_array($extension,$allowedExts)){

        $image=$_FILES['image']['name']; /* STORE THE FILE NAME TO $image VARIABLE */
        $fullpath="ImageDirectory/".$image; /* CHANGE THE NECESSARY FILE DIRECTORY */
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $fullpath); /* MOVE FILE TO THE GIVEN DIRECTORY */

    }

$value = $_POST['titre'] ;
$value2 = $_POST['disponible'] ;
$value3 = $_POST['corrige'] ;
$value4 = $_POST['notes'] ;
$value5 = $_POST['notes2'] ;
$value6 = $_POST['pages'] ;
$value7 = $_POST['monte'] ;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO mode (Titre, Disponible, Corrige, Notescorr, NotesRed, Npages, Monte, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $value, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5, $value6, $value7, $image);
```

### More Note:

- For editing, you need to provide more information about your database and table.
- We need to know the structure of your `mode` table.
- Your table needs to have a *unique ID* in order to update the table in ease.

I'll update my answer as soon as you have provided the needed information.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this It may Help you

create one more column in your table where the data is displaying in the webpage name it as "Edit"

```
<tr>Edit</tr>
```

In the edit column `<td>` value Use loop Like

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

here `$sql`is to fetch all data from your table

now redirect `<a>` link to the update page where you need to see the data and update it.

```
<td><a href = "update.php?id=<?php echo $result[0]?>">Edit</td>
```

here `$result[0]` indicate the primary key column  of the table which redirect the key to the next page and you have now the `primary key` to Update your data inside your table.